# django-background-tasks indefinite run

Tags: python, django, django-views

The docs says,

In Django Background Task, all tasks are implemented as functions (or any other callable).

There are two parts to using background tasks:

```
creating the task functions and registering them with the scheduler
setup a cron task (or long running process) to execute the tasks
```

It appears there is no way to run django-background-tasks indefinitely and periodically, is that correct?

Comment: Why not use a more mature package like: http://www.celeryproject.org ?

Comment: Look at this link. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-background-tasks

Answer (score 0):

If I am understood correctly then You want to execute your tasks periodically without using cron.

You can do using django celery(https://github.com/celery/django-celery) or Task Master (https://github.com/dcramer/taskmaster)

Hope you are wanting this.

Answer (score 0):

you can run the task indefinitely with the repeat like this.

```
task_method(repeat=300)
```

this task will repeat every 300 secconds
you can check the docs here https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#repeating-tasks